# Python - Does PyShark return relative sequence numbers?

Tags: python, wireshark, tshark, pyshark

I know that WireShark is built upon Tshark, and that WireShark displays relative sequence numbers in the GUI for TCP conversations.

I know that PyShark is built upon Tshark.  Does PyShark return relative sequence numbers for TCP conversations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PyShark returns relative sequence numbers for TCP conversations. Meaning that, all new flows will start with a seq number of zero.

See:
http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/

Comment: Is it possible to extract the absolute ones instead?